# Simplepie - fetch feeds from database

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I want to fetch multiple feeds from the database and in so doing fetch all new content from those feeds

it works but there is a problem and I have no idea what's causing it, this is the code:

> $feed_sql = mysqli_query($link,
>   "SELECT feed from tutorial_feed WHERE
>   approved=1");
>
> $feeds = array();
>
> $i = 0;
>
> while($feed_r =
>   mysqli_fetch_object($feed_sql)):
>
> ```
>   $feeds[$i] .= $feed_r->feed;
> ```
>
> $i++;
>
> endwhile;
>
> $feed = new SimplePie($feeds);
>
> $feed->handle_content_type();
>
> foreach($feed->get_items(0, 100) as
>   $item) :
>
> echo $item->get_permalink()."
> ";
>
> endforeach;

I first get

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in I:\wamp\www\cmstut\includes\cron.php on line 22

and then it will start printing the permalinks to the new content based on the imported feeds, I know undefined offset means it does not exist but I don't get it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I found the problem, it was the dot in $feeds[$i] .= $feed_r->feed; that I had to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the dot in $feeds[$i] .= $feed_r->feed; that I had to remove